# how to remove from a querySet

Tags: django

I'm having issues removing from a queryset certain objects in a certain range
like:

```
courses = Course.objects.all().order_by('number')
```

I'd like to exclude courses with number less than 418101.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter these out by using the [**`__gte`** lookup [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#gte):

```
courses = Course.objects.filter(number__gte=418101).order_by('number')
```

This thus means that we filter with `number >= 418101` at the database side.